# Ember.js - Return unicode character from computed property

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to return a unicode character from a computed property, but the `&` keeps getting escaped as `&amp;`.

I've even tried returning a Handlebars SafeString like so:

```
return new Ember.Handlebars.SafeString("&#61573;");
```

...which produces the same results: `&amp;#61573;`

How can I get this working?

**Edit:** This is probably related to the fact that I'm using the computed property in the `valueBinding` of an `{{input}}` helper. The SafeString method does keep the `&` from being escaped *if* I use the value elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

I just created a simple jsbin: http://jsbin.com/izurix/5/edit

Basically doing this does not return any `&amp` for me:

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  value: "&#61573;",
  someValue: function() {
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(this.get('value'));
  }.property('value')
});
```

Furthermore if you don't want that handlebars escapes your string you should use *triple-slash* `{{{someValue}}}`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hm... that doesn't seem to help in my case. Maybe it's because I'm using the property as the `valueBinding` for an `{{input}}`?
At any rate, I was able to copy-paste the unicode value directly into the source. The `` in the code is a little weird, but it will do.
Good tip with the _triple-slash_. It definitely would have worked if I was using the value outside of `{{input}}`. I didn't even know triple-slashes were a thing!